# Weird database icon appears on PHPMyAdmin user interface

Tags: phpmyadmin

On my PHPMyAdmin user interface, I noticed one database which has a strange icon:

[image]

What does this mean? What causes it?

P.S. Note that the database in question functions well (I mean I have no issue with it)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27956560/what-does-the-phpmyadmin-icon-box-of-books-beside-certain-databases-mean